# エラー文を解消したいです: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, python3

```
import ecdsa
import random
from hashlib import sha256

def privatekey():
    n = 1.158 * 10**77
    rng = random.SystemRandom()
    random_num = rng.randint(0, n)
    private_key = int(sha256(str(random_num).encode()).hexdigest(),16)

    while private_key > n:
        random_num = rng.randint(0, n)
        private_key = int(sha256(str(random_num).encode()).hexdigest(),16)

        if private_key < n: 
            print(random_num)
            print(private_key)
            return private_key
            break

    else:
        print(random_num)
        print(private_key)
        return private_key

private_key = privatekey()        

def private_to_public_key(private_key):
    signing_key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(private_key,curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
verifying_key = signing_key.verifying_key
return verifying_key.to_string()

public_key = private_to_public_key(private_key)
print(public_key)
```

このコードでこんなエラー文が出ます。

```
assert len(string) == curve.baselen, (len(string), curve.baselen)

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

どう対処すればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa/blob/master/src/ecdsa/keys.py#L153 を見ますと、`ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string()` を `ecdsa.SigningKey.from_secret_exponent()` に変更すると良さそうです。

Comment: 変更してみました。すると、エラーは出なかったのですがpublic_keyがbyte型で表示されてしまいました。16進数表記したいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか

Comment: リトルエンディアンやビックエンディアンをかければいいのでしょうか？

Comment: `return verifying_key.to_string()` を `return verifying_key.to_string().hex()` としてみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の行を

```
signing_key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(private_key,curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
```

次のように変更すれば、少なくとも`TypeError`は解消するはずです。

```
signing_key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(str(private_key),curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
```

`str`型の引数（1つ目の引数）を受け取ることを想定している`from_string()`に対して、`int`型の引数`private_key`が与えられたことでエラーが発生しているようなので。